# Search in Rotated Sorted Array Leetcode

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

I'm stuck in the [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/). My code keeps returning `3` as output for the input`nums = [4,5,6,7,0,1,2], target = 0`. I'm doing some modified version of binary search and printing the indices of middle index and checking whether value at that index is equal to the target value.Values of middle indices in binary search are `stdout:3 5 4` but instead of returning `4` my program returns `3`. Can you please tell me where my logic is incorrect?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int bin_search(vector<int>& nums,int target,int l,int r){
        int m;
        m=(r+l)/2;
        cout<<m<<" ";
        // if(r==l) break;
        if(nums[m]==target) return m;
        else if(r==l && nums[m]!=target) return -1;
        if(target>=nums[l] && target<=nums[m]){
            m=bin_search(nums,target,l,m);
        }
        else if(target>=nums[m+1] && target<=nums[r]){
            m=bin_search(nums,target,m+1,r);
        }
           
        
        // if(nums[m]==target) return m;
        return m;
    }
    
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int n=nums.size();
        int f;
        f=bin_search(nums,target,0,n-1);
        return f;
    }
};
```

Comment: Binary search can only be used with sorted arrays. (when applying to arrays)

Comment: When you call `bin_search` recursively, what are you doing with the the result those calls *returns*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh thanks ```m=bin_search(nums,target,l,m)``` should be there in the code.

Comment: Note that calling `bin_search()` inside `bin_search()` and throwing the resulting value away makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to think on some modification in the binary search approach because binary search approach is applicable only for sorted array.

**Hint** : Think about finding some subarrays (which are sorted) and then apply binary search only on those specific parts.

Currently, you are not comparing `a[low] & a[mid]`. Only if you compare these two array indices, you'll get an idea of how the array elements are in the subarray (increasing or decreasing).

You are comparing `a[low] & a[mid]` with your `target element` , which will not output the desired relation of subarray(increasing or decreasing)

Comment: I think I'm doing that can you confirm?

Comment: @anfjnlnl if you have any more concerns do let me know!

Comment: Strictly speaking, not only for *sorted* arrays. Take a look at [`std::binary_search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) algorithm requirements.